# json output with rows without key mapping

Tags: python, json

I have this json sample that I'm not sure what is the best way to map "url" and "failedCount" from the columns section with each row in the rows section and then output everything into a csv so that it'll look like this

```
url,failedCount
https://stefanolsen.com/favicon.ico, 663
https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon.png, 282
https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png, 282
```

json sample:

```
{
    "tables":[{
        "name":"Primary",
        "columns":[
        {
            "name":"url",
            "type":"string"
        },
        {
            "name":"failedCount",
            "type":"long"
        }],
        "rows":[
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/favicon.ico", 663],
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon.png", 282],
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png", 282]

        ]
    }]
}
```

Attempted to use code from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_json.html but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking over the contents of the sample JSON input, I think the best approach would be to write something "data-driven" in the sense that the column names weren't hardcoded into it. This would mean it wouldn't need to be changed if they have different names and/or there were a different number of them.

```
import csv
import json

json_sample = '''
{
    "tables":[{
        "name":"Primary",
        "columns":[
        {
            "name":"url",
            "type":"string"
        },
        {
            "name":"failedCount",
            "type":"long"
        }],
        "rows":[
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/favicon.ico", 663],
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon.png", 282],
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png", 282]

        ]
    }]
}'''

filename = 'converted_json.csv'
json_obj = json.loads(json_sample)  # Deserialize.

table = json_obj['tables'][0]  # First table.
fields = [col['name'] for col in table['columns']]  # Extract table field names.

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as outp:  # Create csv file from table.
    writer = csv.writer(outp)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    writer.writerows(table['rows'])

print('done')
```

Comment: Thank you for the approach without hardcoding column names

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is grab the `'rows'` key from the JSON data, it is already in the format you need (which is a list/tuple of lists/tuples).

```
import csv

data = {
    "tables":[{
        ...,
        "rows":[
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/favicon.ico", 663],
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon.png", 282],
            ["https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png", 282]
        ]
    }]
}

rows = data['tables'][0]['rows']

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['url', 'failedCount'])
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Then `test.csv` contains

```
url,failedCount
https://stefanolsen.com/favicon.ico,663
https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon.png,282
https://stefanolsen.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png,282
```

Do not add a space between the comma and the number as it will make it non-trivial to parse the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to do something like this?

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['url', 'failedCount'])
    for table in data['tables']:
        for row in table['rows']:
            writer.writerow([row[0], row[1]])
```